# How to access php session files

Tags: php, session

I have a Yii application with cookie based login enabled.

So , every time a user connects to the application a session file gets created on the server
(/var/lib/php5) related to the PHPSESSID.

One of the Session variables is the timeout (timestamp).

I want to create a php script which access all of these Session files , opens them , checks for the timeout , and if it is timed-out ,make some changes to a specific table in the database.

First problem , from within my php script I'cant open session files in /var/lib/php5.
Permission denied.(AFAIK from my php script I try to open those files as Apache User , though I need to be  superuser , how could that be done...on the fly ? -without changing file permissions)

Second problem.
Even if I try from my php script to open the superglobal $_SESSION for a specific session id
I still get the permission denied message.

```
$sSessId='la05bdm63rdmjevg4hfrcf17u6';
session_id($sSessId);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Any suggestions on how a php script can access those session files ?
Many thnx in advance.

Comment: Store the sessions elsewhere, ex. in the database

Comment: I have no access over this...Yii is doing the whole Session process

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbHttpSession

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion.I'll try...but my question remains in general.
How is it possible to access Session variables from various sessions using phpsessid. (2nd problem)

Answer (score 1):

First you do not need to invoke `session_start()` because by default its true, to disable in the config/main.php

```
'session' => array (
'autoStart' => false,// by default is true
```

),

The best way to read session in Yii is by using the build in functions `Yii::app()->session` which is similar to the super global array `$_SESSION`.

```
Yii::app()->session['var'] = 'value';
echo Yii::app()->session['var'];
```

To unset a session variable

```
unset(Yii::app()->session['var']);
```

To remove a session variable

```
Yii::app()->session->remove('var')
```

to change the path to your session variable

```
'session' => array (
'sessionName' => 'Site Access',
'cookieMode' => 'only',
'savePath' => '/path/to/new/directory',
```

),

Hope this will help

Comment: Yes , but all these are Yii-related commands.
My php script ,which should check the Session Variables of various phpsessionid's, will run on the server (linux) written in plain php.
It will executed by a cron job every 5 minutes.No Yii logic there.

Comment: @Portishead, then in that case please revise your post tags to not say Yii.